# Support for multiple domains in Forms AUthentication

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

Is there a Forms Authentication provider for ASP.Net which supports multiple domains? 
 The problem we are trying to solve is:

- External users access our website using xxx.yyy.com
- Internal users access our website using IP x.x.x.x

We want Forms authentication to work for both these groups of users. Adding an entry to the internal DNS is not an option.
We were able to get this working when we did not set the domain in the Forms tag for forms authentication? What is the domain set to if the default domain is not set explicitly in the Forms tag.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

The form authentication does not depend on the domain. It only depends on a unique `applicationName` for filtering the records if you have a shared Membership database.